# How to Ul tag in script for html

Tags: javascript, php, html

I try to give  for script in html iam using in script of array please give me your suggestions for this coding.

```
<script>

var myArray = [

{

"display": "Home",

"url": "http://jomeitechnologies.com/"

},

{
"display": "About Us",
"url": "http://jomeitechnologies.com/about-us.html"
},

{
"display": "Our Services",
"url": "http://jomeitechnologies.com/our-services.html"
},

{

"display": "Careers",

"url": "http://jomeitechnologies.com/careers.html"
},

{

"display": "Contact Us",

"url": "http://jomeitechnologies.com/contact-us.html" 
}

];

myFunction(myArray);

function myFunction(arr) {

    var out = "";

    var i;

    for(i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {

        out += '<a href="' + arr[i].url + '">' + 

        arr[i].display + '</a><br>';
    }

    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}

</script>
```

Comment: Please specify, What problem are you facing with this code, so others can help you with that. Or if you are looking for code review, consider posting at [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: That's some pretty json you have there.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
function myFunction(arr) {
    var out = '<ul>';
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        out += '<li><a href="' + arr[i].url + '">' + 
               arr[i].display + '</a></li><br>';
    }
    out += '</ul>'
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
```

Comment: Thanks manish i want to know it will display in row wise how to view in column wise

Comment: should have used node notation, but effective either way.